# youtube-v3-api Channel list error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

When I use the test form on the page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list to get my upload ID I do not get the upload ID information in the output.

```
200 OK
- HIDE HEADERS -
cache-control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  184
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 05:09:05 GMT
etag:  "jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/Z9n3n2b5RwRnE9WNo9TXpCBWbY4"
expires:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 05:09:05 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/Z9n3n2b5RwRnE9WNo9TXpCBWbY4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

The command being used to generate this request is

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=StraconisChannel
```

The part that confuses me is I'm doing the same thing as suggested by a tutorial I was following, the only thing I'm changing is the channel name and using my channel name instead.  His output looks like this:

```
200 OK
- HIDE HEADERS -
cache-control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  350
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 05:15:54 GMT
etag:  "jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/ih1aNGvKXcChCR4os4iGDwWDjmQ"
expires:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 05:15:54 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/ih1aNGvKXcChCR4os4iGDwWDjmQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/vDeq-1ACEYq89nbPsEZtYt0KNW0\"",
   "id": "UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "LL29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA",
     "favorites": "FL29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA",
     "uploads": "UU29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "111890735795696959293"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The request used for his results:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=techguyweb
```

I activated the Authorization using OAuth 2.0 so I'm not sure what the issue is.

**Edit**

A comment stated because it was my youtube username and not my google plus account name.  I forgot to put this in to provided information as well.  Which is the same result.

```
200 OK
- HIDE HEADERS -
cache-control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  184
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:10:14 GMT
etag:  "jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/Z9n3n2b5RwRnE9WNo9TXpCBWbY4"
expires:  Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:10:14 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/Z9n3n2b5RwRnE9WNo9TXpCBWbY4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Comment: Because it's your YouTube username, not your google+ account name. Nothing strange

Answer (score 0):

It returns the correct response if you specify channel ID instead of channel name (I got the information via HTTP request but it should work the same for the way you're trying to get the response).

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/pZlhvAUywQ74J9YlQvQ1UqIqanc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/iPoXCMXPqVZgATwZUSDCg0QqeCM\"",
   "id": "UCoyAhNWQms1nSgGbI3rVebQ",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "StraconisChannel",
    "description": "",
    "publishedAt": "2015-09-08T22:33:23.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Yyqu34zJ9zs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/tjDa1pW2Smw/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Yyqu34zJ9zs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/tjDa1pW2Smw/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Yyqu34zJ9zs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/tjDa1pW2Smw/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "StraconisChannel",
     "description": ""
    },
    "country": "US"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UUoyAhNWQms1nSgGbI3rVebQ"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "108236998864115482919"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Make sure you have verified your YouTube channel and connected your channel to a Google+ Page or Profile.